# Bearer authentication with Qt (QNetworkAccessManager)

Tags: c++, rest, qt

I was trying to perform Bearer authentication for [https://developer.olx.ua/api/doc#tag/Adverts/paths/~1adverts/get](https://developer.olx.ua/api/doc#tag/Adverts/paths/%7E1adverts/get) from my Qt app. I use QNetworkAccessManager. But I couldn't find any help on this.

I try this code

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, &loop,
                 &QEventLoop::quit);
const QUrl url("https://www.olx.ua/api/partner/threads");
QNetworkRequest request {url};
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
QString temp = "Bearer " + marketplaceAccessToken;
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", temp.toLocal8Bit());
request.setRawHeader("Version", "2.0");
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
loop.exec();

QByteArray dataReply = reply->readAll();
qDebug() << dataReply;
```

The server reply is `{"error":{"status":400,"title":"Bad Request","detail":"Invalid owner in token"}}`

How can I fix it?

Comment: seems like you have done this correctly, maybe the token is wrong?